# make rpm-maven-plugin work on MAC OS(mavericks)

Tags: java, maven, rpm

I use rpm-maven-plugin to generate installation package. This runs fine on UBUNTU but when i run it on mac os, I met the following errors. Is there a way to make it work on mac os?

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>rpm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

[WARNING] /bin/sh: rpm: command not found
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (default) on project mongodb: RPM query for default vendor returned: '127' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'' -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[it is invoking native `rpm` command](https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/mojo/rpm-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/rpm/RPMHelper.java) which is available in your ubuntu environment, for your apple environment you will have to install rpm executable

```
$ brew install rpm
$ brew install rpmbuild
```

Comment: I don't think rpmbuild exists anymore in homebrew, but installing rpm installed everything that was needed.

Answer (score 4):

Needless to say you can also install it via macports:

---

`$> sudo port install rpm`

--->  Computing dependencies for rpm

--->  Dependencies to be installed: beecrypt neon kerberos5 libcomerr openssl libproxy python27 db48 db_select python_select sqlite3 vala

--->  Fetching archive for beecrypt

--->  Attempting to fetch beecrypt-4.2.1_5.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/beecrypt

...

--->  Applying patches to rpm

--->  Configuring rpm **<== takes a long time**

--->  Building rpm **<== takes a long time**

--->  Staging rpm into destroot

--->  Installing rpm @4.4.9_17

--->  Activating rpm @4.4.9_17

--->  Cleaning rpm

--->  Updating database of binaries

--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors

--->  No broken files found.

`$>`

Note that in the above install, the 'Configuring rpm' and 'Building rpm' steps took a long time, so be patient, it's working in the background (but doesn't print progress markers)

---

`$> which rpm`

/opt/local/bin/rpm

---

I ran into another problem too while running my build; the rpmbuild step failed with: 'Unable to open temp file'.

Solution from https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2002-June/msg00258.html is to

`$> vi $HOME/.rpmmacros`

& add one line to it

`%_tmppath       /tmp`

You should be golden.

Comment: One liner: `echo "%_tmppath /tmp" >> ~/.rpmmacros`